# Client Server Delay for 30 min

Tags: c, client-server

I am writing a client server based election system in C, and I have to give updates to clients after every 30 minutes. Somebody please help me with how I would achieve this. I am a student and not very good with C....

Answer (score 1):

At a high level (and presuming you are using the classic single-threaded server multiplexing with `select()` / `poll()` design):

You record within the data structure associated with each client the time at which the next update to that client is due.  At the point in your code where you are preparing to block on a call like `select()` or `poll()`, you calculate the time remaining until the earliest update is due.  You then use this as the timeout value for the blocking call.

When `select()` / `poll()` returns, as well as checking for active file descriptors, you also check for clients which have reached their "update due" time.  You then send an update to each of these clients, and recalculate the "next update due" time.